# Prove that sum of the $k$ numbers in the $k$th group = ${\frac{1}{2}\left(k(k^2+1)\right)}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider an arrangement of the positive integers, grouped as shown, so that the $k$th group has $k$ elements: $(1),(2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9,10), \ldots$.

The expression for the sum of the $k$ numbers in the $k$th group turns out to be ${\frac{1}{2}\left(k(k^2+1)\right)}$.

However, how would you prove this? I am assuming that you would have to proof by induction, but I can't seem to construct it as of now.

Comment: Each "group" is a finite AP, and its sum is half the number of terms times the "average" term.

Comment: How would you prove this theorem though using induction (or any other method)?

Comment: The induction lies in the formula for the sum of consecutive terms in an arithmetic progression.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Actually, the sum an arithmetic progression is the number of terms times the "average" term, or alternately, half the number of terms times the sum of the first and last terms, as shown in [Arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two patterns:

1. *k*th group has k numbers
2. last number of *k*th group is a triangular number = $\large {k(k+1) \over 2}$

First number of *k*th group = $\large {k(k+1) \over 2} \normalsize - k + 1$

Mean of *k*th group = $\large{k(k+1) - k + 1 \over 2} = {k^2+1 \over 2}$

Sum of *k*th group = $\large {k(k^2+1) \over 2}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_{i,j}$ be the $j$'th term of the $i$'th group. The first element of the $k$'th group is the sum of the previous $1$ to $k - 1$ groups, plus $1$. Since each $i$'th group has $i$ elements, from [Arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), the first term of the $k$'th group is

$$a_{k,1} = 1 + \frac{(k-1)(1 + (k - 1))}{2} = 1 + \frac{k(k-1)}{2} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Since the last term of the $k$'th group would be $1$ less than the first term of the $(k+1)$'th group, \eqref{eq1} gives it would be $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$. Thus, the sum of the $k$'th group is

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
S_k & = \frac{k(a_{k,1} + a_{k,k})}{2} \\
& = \frac{1}{2}k\left(1 + \frac{k(k-1)}{2} + \frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{4}k\left(2 + (k^2 - k) + (k^2 + k)\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{4}k\left(2 + 2k^2\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2}(k(k^2 + 1))
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$